# add button in each row I create in WPF listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

how can I create button in each row I add in listview in c# WPF Like what when you connect to wireless network in windows 7 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the ListView a DataTemplate for it's items.  Try this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCollection}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <Button>Go</Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```